# Binary classification vs. logistic regression

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, binary-operations

Say that we are dealing with binary classification. Explain what needs to be done if there is more than two classes to classify, using logistic regression.

I thought about probabilities but not sure

Comment: You can use one vs all, or you can use some derivatives of logistic regression. All this is conditional on the data.

Comment: @Chinny84, could you explain this some more and put it in the answer section?